# PHP Form not sending an email

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a pre-made form built out of html/css/jquery/ajax. It is pretty much copy and pasted for the time being on my contact page.

This is what i call before my html tag on the contact.php page.

```
<?php

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];


$str='';
if($_SESSION['errStr'])
{
    $str='<div class="error">'.$_SESSION['errStr'].'</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['errStr']);
}

$success='';
if($_SESSION['sent'])
{
    $success='<h1>Success! We will be in contact!</h1>';

    $css='<style type="text/css">#contact-form{display:none;}</style>';

    unset($_SESSION['sent']);
}
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6B2G7/

Here is a jsFiddle for the css/html/jquery. The page loads fine, you can fill in the fields and click submit. It successfully submits, but i receive no email. Spell checked the necessary items, but to no avail, no emails.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry if i left anything out -- new here. Tried using firebug to see if there was an error, but i'm not getting any.

==EDIT==

This is my submit.php, which now i'm wondering where does this need to be? I don't think it's actually calling it anywhere on my site which would explain why no email is being sent. Now i'm a little confused -- first day with PHP. How do i get it to submit to the email address given in the code?

```
<?php

/* config start */

$emailAddress = 'coreymaret@hotmail.com';

/* config end */


require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

    $_POST[$k]=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


$err = array();

if(!checkLen('name'))
    $err[]='The name field is too short or empty!';

if(!checkLen('email'))
    $err[]='The email field is too short or empty!';
else if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    $err[]='Your email is not valid!';

if(!checkLen('subject'))
    $err[]='You have not selected a subject!';

if(!checkLen('message'))
    $err[]='The message field is too short or empty!';

if((int)$_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['expect'])
    $err[]='The captcha code is wrong!';


if(count($err))
{
    if($_POST['ajax'])
    {
        echo '-1';
    }

    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        $_SESSION['errStr'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        $_SESSION['post']=$_POST;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    exit;
}


$msg=
'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />

Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "A new ".mb_strtolower($_POST['subject'])." from ".$_POST['name']." | contact form feedback";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();


unset($_SESSION['post']);

if($_POST['ajax'])
{
    echo '1';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['sent']=1;

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    exit;
}

function checkLen($str,$len=2)
{
    return isset($_POST[$str]) && mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST[$str]),"utf-8") > $len;
}

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}

?>
```

Comment: The random number generator script is all working correctly too.

Comment: where exactly is the part that is supposed to send the email? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: How's your php.ini file looking?

Comment: Saturnix, i edited the original question and included the submit.php code.

Comment: John, thank you for your help as well. I do not have a php.ini file in my directory. I'm a little new to PHP..what exactly is that?

Comment: Is this on a local server or a live one? If you're running locally on a MS box using WAMP or similar, I recommend running Papercut to "receive" the email: http://papercut.codeplex.com/

Comment: Here's my question. I have a submit.php, but it is blank. Logic tells me that the jquery/php uses the submit.php to execute all the filled in fields and sends it to the email given?

Comment: I'm running this on a dreamhost server. ocalaplastering.com/contact.php is where i'm at right now.

The demo i downloaded with the form included the submit.php, there's is filled in. When i open it in dreamweaver, it's also filled in. When i open source up in my browser and view submit.php, it's blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just run submit.php on your browser? Or check spam of your email and try with other email address..

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/

Comment: Odd. It must just be getting stuck in junk mail. I was wondering why it wasn't working..everything was written correctly. Simply trying another email address solved this. Umair, thank you. How i overlooked that..

Comment: Some times it happened. We have to debug block by block :)

Comment: Some email providers simply ignore emails which comes from untrusted sources. If your SMTP server is not properly configured and your "from" address is not from this SMTP it will most likely get blocked. I've tested this months ago with Yahoo. Without SMTP configuration my emails weren't even getting to the spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider the [Mandrill](http://www.mandrillapp.com) API for email. It's really simple to set up:

```js
var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('your_api_key');

function sendTheMail(){
    m.messages.send({
        "message": {
            "from_email": document.getElementById('from_email').value,
            "from_name": document.getElementById('from_name').value,
            "to":[{"email": "your_email", "name": "your_name"}],
            "subject": "optional_value",
            "text": document.getElementById('message').value
        }
    });
}
```

And you could then set up your contact page like this:

```
<p>Your Name: <input type="text" id="from_name"></p>
<p>Your Email: <input type="email" id="from_email"></p>
Message<br><br><textarea rows=15 cols=50 id="message"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="sendTheMail();">Send</button>
```